# What does the term "libration point gateway" mean?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, lagrangian-points, celestial-mechanics, low-energy-transfer, three-body

In the Circular Restricted Three Body Problem, natural paths exist between periodic orbits or the libration points that have negligible cost. These are commonly known as free transfers between libration point orbits. These paths also supply transfers between whats-so-called "libration point gateways".

However, I was wondering what is the difference between "transfers between libration point orbits" and "transfers libration point gateways" ? Aren't they the same?

Comment: Giving a source where these two different terminologies are used would help to clear the confusion!

Comment: I have never heard of the term "libration point gateway" but the upcoming LOP-G station is often called "The Gateway" and will be in a libration point orbit (a near rectilinear halo orbit, NRHO, to be exact).

Answer (score -1):

The Lagrangian points are gravitationally so close to each other that "free" transfers between them, and nearby orbits, exist.

Both "transfers between libration point orbits" and "libration point gateways" refer to this fact.

The term "libration point gateways" is rare enough that you would have to presisely define it if you want to use it. Without context, like this, it's ambiguous. A plausible interpretation is that it refers to the parts of the connected system of libration point orbits where one can conveniently enter from or leave to the outside.